# Showing main website title in biblatex-apa bibliography

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

I'm using `biblatex-apa` and `biber` to write my research paper in APA format. I love using BibDesk and LaTeX compared to manually writing the bibliography in Pages, but I can't figure out the online bibliography types.

The Purdue OWL has a sample of an online periodical article,

> Brownlie, D. (2007). Toward effective poster presentations: An
>   annotated bibliography. *European Journal of Marketing, 41*,
>   1245-1283. doi:10.1108/03090560710821161

I can do this citation using the article type, but I would need a field for the DOI, how would I do this?

Also, for regular websites, I need the website title to appear in italics. Using `biblatex-apa`, the title of the webpage is not set in italics...?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The field for DOI is - you guessed it - `doi`. In your case that would be `doi = {10.1108/03090560710821161},`. To the `title` of `@online` entries in italics try `\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`.

Comment: Thanks, @moewe, the `\DeclareFieldFormat` trick is nifty. Do you know of any site that has a list of all the keys I can use? I'd like to not have to guess at tag names... ;)

Comment: By 'keys' do you mean 'entry fields'?  If so, the complete list is given in the `biblatex` manual.  On a TeX Live system, you can do `texdoc biblatex`; otherwise, check out [texdoc.net](texdoc.net) and search for 'biblatex'.

Comment: You can find all the information you need, and much more, in the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) (the [`texdoc.net` version](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) seems to be about an older release). § 2 would be of interest to you for all the entry types and their entry fields.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the assistance! Here is the solution I used to format the online periodical article:

```
@article{pkacancer,
Author = {Caretta, Antonio and Mucignat-Caretta, Carla},
Date-Added = {2013-10-13 16:24:30 +0000},
Date-Modified = {2013-10-13 18:23:51 +0000},
Doi = {10.3390/cancers3010913},
Journal = {Cancers},
Number = {3},
Pages = {913-926},
Title = {Protein Kinase A in Cancer},
Url = {www.mdpi.com/2072-6694/3/1/913/pdf},
Urldate = {2013-10-13},
Year = {2011}}
```

To italicize the title, I used this code in the preamble for my document:

```
\documentclass[man, 12pt, biblatex-apa]{apa6}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english, british]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
\addbibresource{workscited.bib}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\DeclareFieldFormat[online]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

Comment: I'm no expert in bibliographies, but I thought article would be better because it was in a journal originally. By providing the DOI I showed that it was an online document.